# EclipseのJUnitファイルテンプレートを編集したい

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse neon.1を使っています。
例えば、ProjectExplorerのコンテキストメニューから、New→Other→JUnit→JUnit Test Caseでウィザードから生成されるソースコードですが、このソースコードのテンプレートを編集したいです。
具体的には、importに追加したいものがあります。
可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

次のリンク先に同様の質問がありましたが、回答としては「ハードコードされているので設定での変更は不可能」なようです。

- [Customized new JUnit templates in Eclipse? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1345230/4506703)

少し古い質問でしたので現状のコードも見てみましたが、[やはり当時と同様ハードコードされているようでした](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.junit/src/org/eclipse/jdt/junit/wizards/NewTestCaseWizardPageOne.java?id=65467ee0a350e6890dec0b74844dbdcf86f02b68#n721)。

---

代替案としては、上記リンク先にもありますが、コンテンツアシスト(Windowsなら<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>で実行できる)のテンプレート機能を用いる方法が考えられます。
Preferencesの`Java > Editor > Templates`より Nameが**test** (Descriptionは **test method (JUnit 4)** )の項目を編集します。

デフォルトでは次のようになっていますが、

```
@${testType:newType(org.junit.Test)}
public void ${testName}() throws Exception {
    ${staticImport:importStatic('org.junit.Assert.*')}${cursor}
}
```

これを例えば

```
@${testType:newType(org.junit.Test)}
public void ${testName}() throws Exception {
    ${staticImport:importStatic('org.junit.Assert.*')}${imp:import('java.util.logging.Logger')}${cursor}
}
```

とすると、コンテンツアシストでテストメソッドを生成した際に、(存在しなければ)`import java.util.logging.Logger`が挿入されます。

ここで使用できる変数については、既存のテンプレートや次のリンク先が参考になるかと思います。

- [Eclipse Galileo でJava コーディングを迅速に行うための追加事項](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/opensource/library/os-eclipse-galcode/#variables)